# Gradle Spring Cloud Stream project does not build because of test dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

When I try to build a Gradle Spring Boot project with Spring Cloud Stream I receive the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':testCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:test-binder.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:test-binder.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:test-binder.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams:3.0.9.RELEASE > org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core:3.0.9.RELEASE
```

The project works fine if I remove the following dependency:

`testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:test-binder@test-jar'`

The project was generated using Spring initilizr with this [configuration](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.3.6.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-stream,kafka).

What can I change so the project builds successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:test-binder@test-jar'
```

to

```
testImplementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream") {
        artifact {
            name = "spring-cloud-stream"
            extension = "jar"
            type ="test-jar"
            classifier = "test-binder"
        }
}
```

Currently, Spring Initializr generates Gradle projects with this error and the problem is documented in [#1159](https://github.com/spring-io/initializr/issues/1159) and
[#591](https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/issues/591).